# Vaadin 14 Spring Boot App run from command line in ProductionMode

Tags: spring-boot, maven, vaadin14

I want to run the spring boot application from a jar with embedded tomat, like I run other spring-boot apps.

The project is running fine, when started from IDE.
I want to run it from jar, but i get this error in the browser:

```
Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers.
```

I have set the productionMode to true in both application.properties and pom.xml. Why it is such a hustle? I don't know how to produce this json file. How to just run this project even in dev mode?

I start the project with:

```
mvn clean && mvn package -Pproduction && mvn spring-boot:run -Pproduction
```